# Canonical Complete Residue System $\pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all solutions in the canonical complete residue system modulo $7$ of the congruence

$$3x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$

I know that there is a unique solution, because $\operatorname{gcd}(3, 7)=1$ which is obviously a divisor of $2$. However, I don't exactly where I need to go from there in order to get to the general solution.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the congruence $3x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$, we can apply the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
$$7 = 2 \cdot 3 + 1$$
Solving for $1$ yields 
$$1 = 7 - 2 \cdot 3$$
Hence, 
$$3 \cdot -2 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$
Multiplying both sides of the congruence by $2$ yields
$$3 \cdot -4 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$$
Since $-4 \equiv 7 - 4 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, we obtain
$$3 \cdot 3 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$$
Hence, $x \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$.

**Check:** If $x \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, then $3x \equiv 3 \cdot 3 \equiv 9 \equiv 7 + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

A method that will always work is to use Euclid's algorithm to find integers $a,b$ such that $$3a + 7b = 1,$$ which is possible since $\mathrm{gcd}(3,7) = 1$. Then observe that $$3a \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$so $$3(2a) \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$and hence $x=2a\pmod 7$ is the required solution.

In this case, since $7$ is small, you'll be better off working manually. There are $6$ possibilities for $x$, and as you've said, exactly one of them must work.